# Flying character in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

I have currently got my character flying in the air with the following script

```
#pragma strict

var cMotor: CharacterMotor; // reference to the CharacterMotor script

function Start(){ // get the CharacterMotor script at Start:
cMotor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
}

function Update(){ // move player upwards while F is pressed
if (Input.GetKey("f")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.up*10.5);}
else if (Input.GetKey("up")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.forward*10.5);
}
else if (Input.GetKey("left")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.left*10.5);
}
else if (Input.GetKey("down")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.back*10.5);
}
else if (Input.GetKey("right")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.right*10.5);
}
else if (Input.GetKey("g")){
cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.down*10.5);
}
}

// This do-nothing function is included just to avoid error messages
// because SetVelocity tries to call it

function OnExternalVelocity(){
}
```

however I want to be able to freeze the character in the air so they do not fall but if I set the maxFallSpeed to 0 then I cannot make the character land again. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is java script, it would be worth adding that tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use default "w,s,a,d" to move and "f,g" for up and down.

```
#pragma strict

var cMotor: CharacterMotor; // reference to the CharacterMotor script

function Start(){ // get the CharacterMotor script at Start:
   cMotor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
}

function Update(){ // move player upwards while F is pressed

if (Input.GetKey("f")){
    cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.up*6);
}else if(Input.GetKeyUp("f")){
    cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.up*0);
}


 if(Input.GetKey("g")){
     cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.down*6);
}else if(Input.GetKeyUp("g")) {
    cMotor.SetVelocity(Vector3.down*0);
}
}

// This do-nothing function is included just to avoid error messages
// because SetVelocity tries to call it

function OnExternalVelocity(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the CharacterMotor since its not a default unity3d script but something you have written yourself or taking from a tutorial.
but with that in mind, might i suggest that you disable the rigidbody when no key is pressed.

```
function Update() {
    if(!Input.anyKey) {
       Rigidbody.mass = 0.0f;
       Rigidbody.drag = 50;
    } else {
       Rigidbody.mass = 1.0f; // or the stored variabled of the initial mass
       Rigidbody.drag = 0.7f; 
    }
}
```

Its a crude method, but it will work. the question is just if your character motor is using any charactercontroller.move or simplemove that will drag the character down as well.

if so add a boolean to your character motor and when doing the gravity check just disable the bool with the Input.anyKey which will return true if any key is pressed and false if no key is being held down.

edit: code changes as defined in the comments below.

Comment: Rigidbody does not have an `enabled` field.  It is a `Component`, but it's not a `MonoBehavior`.  You need to call `rigidBody.Sleep()` and `rigidBody.WakeUp()` instead.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that is actually true, you could also change its mass, setting it to 0 would make the player stay in air, but still be able to process any other environmental changes.

Comment: very true, the simplest solution would be to just have it sleep, but as stated it would be preferable to have it alive and be able to take in other changes, other than gravity. you could always increase drag also of the rigidbody. lets say a plane flies in to the player, with the rigidbody turned off, it might get unwanted results.